# Связь free() и NULL в Си

Tags: c

Эквивалентны ли эти выражения

```
free(ptr);

ptr = NULL;
```

Если нет, то в чем разница

Comment: Совершенно не эквивалентны. Функция `free` освобождает память, на которую указывает указатель `ptr`. А выражение `ptr = NULL` просто обнуляет указатель. При обнулении указателя память, на которую он указывал, не освобождается.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В С нет *сборщиков мусора*, поэтому обнуление указателя даст в лучшем (или худшем) случае утечку памяти.

```
free(ptr);
```

Освобождает *ранее выделенную* память, на которую указывает `ptr`; сама переменная `ptr` остается с тем же значением, что и раньше - указателем на выделенную (и освобожденную) память.

```
prt = NULL;
```

Изменяет значение *переменной* `ptr` на `NULL`; на память, на которую она указывает, не действует никак.

Но обе эти строки можно писать вместе - чтобы освободить память, и занулить переменную, т.е. чтобы случайно не обратиться к уже освобожденной памяти.

Answer (score 4):

Уточняющий ответ к предыдущему:

1. Затирая указатель на адрес блока выделенной памяти через `(m/c/re)alloc`, не возвращается выделенная область памяти, менеджеру памяти (ОС - операционной системе).
2. Все параметры в [c](/questions/tagged/c), передаются по значению, а это говорит о том, что передача указателя в функцию, не позволит изменить значение этого указателя, т.е. после вызова функции `free`, адрес переданный на освобождение, будет иметь тот же адрес что и до вызова.

Подробнее читайте в стандарте: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A647%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C-27%2C816%2Cnull%5D